# VSCode: how to configure my project to automatically activate Python extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

To activate Python extension in VSCode I must open a Python file. Can I activate it without opening a Python file?

I saw [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5553), but couldn't see if there is a configuration in my workspace settings to do it. If I open a python file the extension is activated and my venv loaded, but I'd like to do it without opening a file.

Comment: does the extension mentioned in the issue work for you

Comment: @rioV8 I'm using the python extension. My code does not have some standard python files (e.g. requirements.txt is in a subdir)

Comment: I mean [extension by DonJayamanne](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5553#issuecomment-493549505), it only calls the `activate` method of the python extension